# Why "_=1389258551926" sent as query string parameters on ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery Ajax to send request to my action class with `data: {campaignId: campaignId}` but `_=1389258551926` also sent as data.

My ajax request function is:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var campaignId = $('#campaign').val();
    alert("Ajax request ; Camp : " + campaignId);
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "getCampData",
        data: {campaignId: campaignId},
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("Camp List : " + data.campList);
});
```

Query String parameters:

```
campaignId=Test&_=1389258551927
```

Why this extra parameter sent as data?

Comment: It is for "cache busting"; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687729/who-add-single-underscore-query-parameter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657604/preventing-jquery-from-cache-busting-resources-loaded-during-ajax-callbacks-that

Comment: I bet you sent it at `Thu Jan 09 2014 03:09:11 (-6)`. It sends a timestamp so that the browser will request the file from the server instead of from the browser's cache.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This parameter is a timestamp. You can see it's strangely alike what you'd get in the console with

```
Date.now()
```

This is done to ensure the URL changes and avoid receiving a cached version of the page.

It's described in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: Yeah but why the timestamp was added ? he didnt mention cache:false

Comment: @Jazzepi cache:true is not adding the postfix

Comment: There could be a call to [ajaxsetup](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) somewhere else.