# Two request being sent from browser but only localhost is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I have an node js API.

```
app.post('/myapi', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Request-With");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.header("Accept", "application/json");
    * do something *
    res.json({ api : "api called successfully" });
});
```

I have a html code placed in the public folder. I am using express to run both the html code and backend APIs. 
My html code has request fetch as,

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*');

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(loginDetails),
  headers: headers,
  mode: 'no-cors'
};
fetch('http://localhost:3001/myapi', options)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  res=response.statusCode;
  // return response
  if (res==0) {
    window.location.assign("http://localhost:3001/home.html");
  }
```

});

When I run the code in browser. When I click on a button that calls the above frontend code. It sends two request. Both the call fails. One is localhost request which is document call and other is the API call. But there is no response in the API call.

I was getting response in UI from the / call,

```
cannot POST/
```

So I tried adding following code,

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({ "status": "successfull" });
});
```

Now also there is two calls but UI returns {status : successfull} (output of /). But it is not returning output of /myapi.

Can someone please help?

I am getting an infinity initiator for localhost document. See the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Hi do you have an error message to share?

Comment: Hi, I am not getting an error message. But the call to /myapi is getting cancelled but the browser is loading the "localhost:port/" response. Both are on same origin.

Comment: Using your code I was unable to recreate the issue. I was able to receive the requests. Do you have any other details?

Answer (score 0):

Append any unique parameter to request to avoid sending cached version of request.

`/api/name?id=<unique_param>`

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016070/why-1389258551926-sent-as-query-string-parameters-on-ajax-request) and [here](http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/07/31/double-requests/).

Comment: The problem does not seam to be a cached request. It looks like the request is either not going through or is not being accepted by node considering the response `cannot POST/`